# Third party library fails with NoSuchMethodError in Storm

Tags: scala, apache-storm

my topology running on Storm fails with a NoSuchMethodError scala.Predef$.doubleWrapper in a bolt because a third-party library requires a later version of Scala (2.11.x) than bundled with Azure HDInsight 3.6 (Storm 1.1.0, Scala 2.9.2). I included the later Scala library in the fat jar using the maven-assembly-plugin and tried to pass the 2.11 Scala Jar with the --jar option of the Storm CLI jar command, but Storm still uses the older Scala version.

Any idea how I can force the topology to overwrite a library already provided by Storm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Storm bundles Scala. At least I don't see it in the 1.1.0 release zip.

Normally, the libraries Storm puts on the classpath will be in the storm/lib or storm/extlib directories on your Storm install. I haven't used HDInsight, so I don't know what kind of access you have, but if HDInsight puts Scala on the classpath for Storm, it's a good bet the jar might be in one of those folders. If you find it there, you could just replace it with the version you need.

Comment: You're right. Just replacing the jar in storm/extlib works. But has to be done on all supervisor and nimbus nodes. Just hoping it does not have any side-effects.